# vue 3 watch specific object's item from array

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am working on nuxt 3 (vue 3) and I need to watch the particular item of the specific object from the array.

**My array**

```js
const formData = reactive({
   addressDetails: [
     {
      address: "",
      street: "",
      suburb: "",
      state: "",
      postCode: "",
      country: "",
      unitNumber: "",
      streetNumber: "",
      streetName: "",
      timeAtaddressYears: "",
      timeAtaddressMonths: "0",
    },
   ]      
});
```

Here, I want to watch if any `timeAtaddressYears` items value has changed but not on the whole  `formData.addressDetails` value. Ex if I add new address details then no need to any watch but in specific address details if I change any address's `timeAtaddressYears` then watch should be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a similar one, we need to add a **deep watcher** if we want to watch the particular item of the specific object from the array.

[VueJS Deepwatchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers)

```js
watch(
  () => formData,
  (newValue, oldValue) => {
    console.log(newValue, oldValue);
  },
  { deep: true });
```

Comment: As per I know we can also watch formData.addressDetails only because if formData contains other state than addressDetails it will also watch for those too.

Answer (score 2):

```
const formData = reactive({
   addressDetails: [
     {
      address: "",
      street: "",
      suburb: "",
      state: "",
      postCode: "",
      country: "",
      unitNumber: "",
      streetNumber: "",
      streetName: "",
      timeAtaddressYears: "",
      timeAtaddressMonths: "0",
    },
   ]      
})

const selected = computed(() => {
  return formData.addressDetails.map(form => form.timeAtaddressYears)
})

watch(selected, (newValue, oldValue) => {
      console.log(newValue, oldValue)
})
```

Comment: As I mentioned I am working with nuxt 3 and nuxt 3 is based on Vue 3 so this syntax will not work and I need an extra level watch as I mentioned. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya Now I added code with VUE3 syntax and you have to do some modification with your logic and It will be help for you. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your revert try! I think it is a lengthy process using computed and watch both to indicate only one change. I have posted the answer on my way as per the Vue 3 documentation

Comment: Okay, My code is working for only change value of timeAtaddressYears from your array of object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
watch(() => formData.addressDetails[0].address, (newValue, oldValue) => {

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I also need to watch if formData.addressDetails[1].address value has changed.

Comment: if(formData.addressDetails[1].address !== previousAddressValue) {
    console.log("The address valuechanged.");
} try this may be works

Comment: It will not work. I think you didn't clear with requirements. Please check the whole thing first and address details are dynamic and it is not fixed user can add or remove any address